# Правильное значение слова "нелицеприятный"

Tags: значение-слов

Не могу до конца уложить в голове смысл слова "нелицеприятный". Я слышал его в разных значениях и не знаю, какое из них верное.
В одном случае говорили примерно так: "Он высказался о тебе в нелицеприятных выражениях" (в смысле, как у Жванецкого: "Ваша буфетчица так часто нехорошо говорит, что, кажется, и думает нехорошо"))). В другом случае слово "нелицеприятный" употреблялось в значении "объективный", в своих суждениях не выделяющий любимчиков.
Какое же из этих значений верное?

Comment: для этого слова просматриваются ДВА ЗНАЧЕНИЯ: неприятный, но беспристрастный, соответствующий действительности." (с) - ну и где тут ДВА значения?!?!? = какое второе ???

Comment: Читайте внимательнее: 1) неприятный, но беспристрастный; 2) соответствующий действительности = объективный.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Какова разница между "беспристрастный" и "объективный"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно определение «нелицеприятный» употребляется по отношению к речи: нелицеприятный разговор об ошибках, нелицеприятный упрек, нелицеприятный отзыв об искусстве артиста.  И не вызывает сомнение, что такие ситуации не только нелицеприятны, но и неприятны тоже.

Хотя "нелицеприятный" чаще определяется как беспристрастный, справедливый, но в действительности «нелицеприятный» мотивируется «отсутствием лицеприятия», и связь между этими значениями причинно-следственная: кто-то откровенно, беспристрастно и, возможно, справедливо говорит о неприятных вещах, о которых обычно умалчивается. Поэтому для этого слова просматриваются ДВА ЗНАЧЕНИЯ: неприятный, но беспристрастный, соответствующий действительности.

Итак, нелицеприятная речевая ситуация обычно неприятна тоже (первое значение слова). Но по отношению к людям проявляется другое значение: справедливый, не любящий угождать и не угождающий из корыстных побуждений, например:

Он  нелицеприятный критик.

Я человек нелицеприятный: никогда не скажу «люблю» тому, кого не люблю.

Перед нами уже не мститель, а строгий, нелицеприятный судья.

Answer (score 3):

И то, и другое.

НЕЛИЦЕПРИЯТНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -тен, -тна, -тно. Книжн.
Беспристрастный, справедливый. Н-ая критика. Н. отзыв. Н-ое мнение. < Нелицеприятно, нареч. Н. отозваться об авторе. Он судил всегда н.

(Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова)

Comment: >> но и резкая, беспардонная, не учитывающая личность критикуемого

Вы не правы, такого оттенка у слова "нелицеприятный" нет.

Answer (score 1):

Такой оттенок у слова считается просторечием, грубой речевой ошибкой. [См. в Викисловаре](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%ED%E5%EB%E8%F6%E5%EF%F0%E8%FF%F2%ED%FB%E9)

Comment: Неясно сформулировано. Какой оттенок? Догадаться можно, но лучше ответ поправить.