# "Нелицеприятно" в значении "плохо"

Tags: семантика, значение-слов

Нередко в быту и даже в телевизионных программах слова *нелицеприятно*, *нелицеприятные* упортебляют в значении *плохо*, *плохие* (он говорил о ней нелицепрятно, она говорила о нём нелицеприятные вещи). Корректно ли употребление слова *нелицеприятно* в таком значении?

Comment: Повтор вопроса http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39549/Правильное-значение-слова-нелицеприятный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    он говорил о ней нелицеприятно, она говорила о нём нелицеприятные вещи
```

Если говорил/говорила в лицо - корректно, потому что в данном значении это синонимы: непредвзято, справедливо, честно, хотя неприятно для данного лица.

А если за глаза, то это речевая ошибка: не всё, что плохо, неприятно, обидно, можно назвать нелицеприятным, т. е. не основанным на угодничестве, лицеприятии.

◆ Вместо приветствий американского президента встречают плакатами нелицеприятного содержания. Андрей Никонов, «ОДКБ меняет формат»

◆ Во всяком случае, он сумел создать у нас атмосферу искренности и нелицеприятного говорения правды друг другу в глаза, а это одно уже было очень важно. В. П. Астафьев, «Зрячий посох», 1978–1982 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка)
неправ.

Answer (score 1):

Лицеприятие - необъективность. Чем же плоха объективность, она разве что неприятна, ибо бесстрастна? Нелицеприятность неудобна и заметна в обществе условностей. Только тем и плоха, и только для тех, кто не способен правильно отнестись к критике в свою сторону.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что у слова "нелицеприятно" появилось значение "плохо" вместо значения "объективно". У народа-смыслотворца появилось ).

Comment: Без комментариев. Мягко говоря.